# Typescript compiler is sometimes ignoring structure yet other times it keeps the folder structure?

Tags: typescript, tsc

The typescript compiler is supposed to compile the files under `./` to `./build/`, which consist of several directories one containing the typescript source `./src/`. This is done by the following typescript config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es2019",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib":  ["es2015","es2020"],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */

    "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "build",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
 
    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */


  },
  "exclude": [
    ".idea",
    "build",
    "node_modules",
    "typings/globals",
    "typings/modules",
    "test"
  ]
}
```

Now I notice that the final build files are no longer in the `src` directory in the build but in the main `./src/app.ts` would get compiled to `./build/app.js`

This isn't a problem of itself, I could just change the output directory. However whenever I remove the `test` directory -which contains typescript- from the excluded directories. Or when I add a second source directory the compiling suddenly *doesn't* flatten the top level of directories.

And `./src/app.ts` becomes `./build/src/app.js`.

This makes further processing quite hard. So can I make it so it doesn't try to flatten the root directory? -- Even explicitly stating the root directory causes this "flattening". So specifying `./src/` as one of the roots wouldn't work as that directory itself might be flattened if it just contains a single child directory with typescript.

Comment: I currently see similar behavior. I only need one js file for a static html page and I want to build this js with typescirpt. I added a ts file in /typescript/events/events.ts and want it to be compiled to /public/events/events.js but it is compiled to /public/events.js. Only when I add a second file in another folder (/typescript/foo/bar.ts) both are compiled into their folders events and foo